# Draw a texture in OpenGL while ignoring its alpha channel

Tags: opengl, textures, alpha, alphablending, premultiplied-alpha

I have a texture loaded into memory that is of RGBA format with various alpha values.

The image is loaded as so:

```
 GLuint texture = 0;
 glGenTextures(1, &texture);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
 self.texNum = texture;

 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 

 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [self.imageData bytes]);
```

I want to know how I can draw this texture so that the alpha channel in the image is treated as all 1's and the texture is drawn like an RGB image.

Consider the base image:

[image: http://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/~jcoplan/alpha/base.png]

This image is a progression from 0 to 255 alpha and has the RGB value of 255,0,0 throughout

However if I draw it with blending disabled I get an image that looks like:
www.ldeo.columbia.edu/~jcoplan/alpha/no_alpha.png

When what I really want is an image that looks like this:
www.ldeo.columbia.edu/~jcoplan/alpha/correct.png

I'd really appreciate some pointers to have it ignore the alpha channel completely.  Note that I can't just load the image in as an RGB initially because I do need the alpha channel at other points.

Edit:  I tried to use GL_COMBINE to solve my problem as such:

```
glColorf(1,1,1,1);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_ALPHA, GL_PRIMARY_COLOR);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA); 
[self drawTexture];
```

But still no luck, it draws black to red still.

Comment: Both the solutions suggested look correct. Look at the pointer returned by [self.imageData bytes] in the debugger's memory view. Are the values what you expect? The results you are getting suggest they won't be...

Comment: Are you using pre-multiplied alpha?  If so, then the fade-to-black is what the RGB values of your texture contain.  What is your glBlendFunc?

Comment: @Alan & brone
After looking at they bytes this is correct, the image was being pre-multiplied through an XCode optimization and the bytes internally were not what I expected.

So the answer is that I'm not loading the image correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a texture loaded into memory that is of RGBA format with various alpha values

glDisable(GL_BLEND)

> However if I draw it with blending disabled I get an image that looks like: www.ldeo.columbia.edu/~jcoplan/alpha/no_alpha.png

This happens because in your source image all transparent pixels are black. It's a problem with your texture/image, or maybe with loader function, but it is not an OpenGL problem.

You could probably try to fix it using glTexEnv(GL_COMBINE... ) (i.e. mix texture color with underlying color based on alpha channel), but since I haven't done something like that, i'm not completely sure, and can't give you exact operands. It was possible in Direct3D9 (using D3DTOP_MODULATEALPHA_ADDCOLOR), so most likely there is a way to do it in opengl.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by all my transparent pixels are black. 

I tried a GL_COMBINE as such but no luck, it still draws black to red...

Comment: @jcoplan: transparentcy is just another channel. If pixel has R255, G0, B0, A255, it is non-transparent RED. If it has R255, G0, B0, A0, it is completely transparent RED. If it has R0, G0, B0, A0, then it is completely transparent BLACK. In your texture color is a gradient that interpolates linearly from transaprent BLACK (R0,G0,B0,A0) to non-transparent RED (R255G0B0A255). That's why you see black parts. If you want another result, you need another picture. Still, I'd recommend to use two different images. When gradient is present in both A and RGB, it may not look nice on white background.

Comment: You're correct that I wasn't loading the image correctly.  I was suffering from a surprise alpha pre-multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

You should not disable blending but use the [glBlendFunc](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glBlendFunc.3G.html) with proper parameters:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
```

Comment: I thought to try that but the image still comes out looking like this:
www.ldeo.columbia.edu/~jcoplan/alpha/no_alpha.png

Answer (score 0):

Or you could tell OpenGL to upload only the RGB channels of your image using

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4)
```

before you call `glTexImage2D` with format set to `GL_RGB`. It will cause it to skip the fourth byte of every pixel, i.e. the alpha channel.

Comment: GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT affects the alignment of *rows*, not individual pixels. See http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPixelStorei.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and found out that it was because iOS image loading was doing a premultiply on the RBG values (as discussed in some of the other answers and comments here).  I'd love to know whether there's a way of disabling pre-multiplication, but in the meantime I'm "un-pre-multiplying" using code derived from [this thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-game-development/52404-dark-borders-alpha-blended-sprites.html) and [this thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5139-opengl-rendering-issue.html).

```
    // un pre-multiply
    uint8_t *imageBytes = (uint8_t *)imageData ;
    int byteCount = width*height*4 ;
    for (int i=0; i < byteCount; i+= 4) {
        uint8_t a = imageBytes[i+3] ;
        if (a!=255 && a!=0 ){
            float alphaFactor = 255.0/a ;
            imageBytes[i] *= alphaFactor ; 
            imageBytes[i+1] *= alphaFactor ; 
            imageBytes[i+2] *= alphaFactor ; 
        }
    }
```